# Connect multiple devices in GoPro network

Tags: android, wifi, android-wifi, gopro

I developed a simple proof of concept app to connect to my GoPro Hero 3+ and control it remotely. The app is working fine and from my Moto G I can power on, power off, start recording, etc.

Now, I have a problem. This is my scenario:

- I have a client app running in a Samsung Galaxy S3. This client collects data from sensors: Accelerometer, Gyroscope, etc.
- I have a server app running in my Moto G. This server receives data from Galaxy S3 through a socket. Both devices are connected in my router network.

The problem now is: I want to add my PoC app in this whole history, but GoPro obligates that the device who sends commands to it must be connected to GoPro Network. So, in this case I have two options:

- Put all the devices (Moto G, Galaxy S3 and GoPro) in the GoPro network and establish all connections between devices in this network. It doesn't work: My client app in Galaxy S3 cannot connect to Moto G. It simply doesn't work. I can ping GoPro Camera (ip 10.5.5.9) from MotoG (10.5.5.109 ip) and from Galaxy S3 (ip 10.5.5.108), but I can't ping MotoG from Galaxy S3 and vice-versa.
- In some manner, connect GoPro in a specific network, in this case the network from my router. So, my router would manager all this stuff and everyhing would work, but I don't know if this is possible.

Thanks in advance, guys!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you are going to have issues.  I've been working with multiple gopros for the last few weeks and I can say that they were definitely not meant for easy extension.

I can answer your second point with a definite no.  The GoPro is the access point and as far as I can tell you would need to hack the GoPro to make it act as a client and not an access point.

As for the former, I suspect that the same "access point" only operation is also playing havoc there as well and you won't be able to talk across the network that way.  I assume of course that all the subnet, host and whatnot is all correct between all devices.